# Set view background from image view

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to match whatever image is placed in a `UIImageView` with the background image of the view controller's view. So when the user calls `func call` in the example below, whatever image is in the image view `choosenBack` is displayed as the background of the view controller. If no image is placed in the image view, the view background image should just be `nil`.

```
choosenBack = UIImageView()

func call(){
    self.view.backgroundColor == UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(choosenBack)!)
}
```

Comment: What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `backgroundColor` property will only work when you indeed want the image to be repeated to fill the background. In that case you could simply do something like

```
func call() {
    if let image = choosenBack.image {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    } else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white // Or w/e your default background is
    }
}
```

If you want the background image to *not* repeat, you'll need to use a dedicated background image view.

```
let background = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    background.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // Or w/e your desired content mode is

    view.insertSubview(background, at: 0)
    background.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    background.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    background.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    background.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    background.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    ...
}

func call() {
    self.background.image = choosenBack.image
}
```